# Binary Matrix from Array of Pairs

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, binary

i'm having a following problem in java:

i'm trying to create a binary matrix where the input is an array of Pairs

```
ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> inputArray = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
```

So lets say it looks like this:

```
[(argument1, value1), 
 (argument1, value2), 
 (argument1, value4),
 (argument2, value2), 
 (argument2, value4), 
 (argument3, value1),
 (argument3, value2),
 (argument3, value3),]
```

The expected output would be:

```
           value1   value2   value3   value4
argument1     1        1       0        1
argument2     0        1       0        1
argument3     1        1       1        0
```

I know there are answers on this forum how to create a binary array, but i didn't find anything how to do it having an array of pairs.

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Output

```
short[][] matrix = new short[rows][columns];
```

Comment: A requirement for the output structure ?

Comment: So the output should be: `short[][] binaryMatrix = new short[count(arguments)][count(values)];`

Comment: you cannot use a `short` array, because you'll lost the "argument1" and "value1" Strings ? or you don't matter to keep the String, and only want a 0/1 array of array ?

Comment: here is solution with `short[][]` and if erquires to keep the String, a solution with `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`

Comment: Seriously ? You seemed ok with a solution which just gives the structure to hold your values,you never talk about printing, right, think about vote up some answers also maybe

Comment: Sorry - im newbie here and thought i can you both give the right answer mark. Voting up is also not possible for me yet: /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using a `Map<String, Map<String,Integer>>`, from first map you'll choose tha `argument`, and on the second you'll choose the `value` and get a `0` or a `1`

   ```
   ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val1"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val2"));
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val4"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag2", "val2"));
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag2", "val4"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val2"));
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val2"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val3"));

   List<String> arguments = list.stream().map(Pair::getKey).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
   List<String> values = list.stream().map(Pair::getValue).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

   Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();

   for(String ag : arguments){
       map.putIfAbsent(ag, new TreeMap<>());

       for(String val : values){
           if(list.contains(new Pair<>(ag,val))){
               map.get(ag).put(val, 1);
           }else{
               map.get(ag).put(val,0);        
           }
       }

   }
   System.out.println(map);
   //{ag1={val1=1, val2=1, val3=0, val4=1}, 
      ag2={val1=0, val2=1, val3=0, val4=1}, 
      ag3={val1=0, val2=1, val3=1, val4=0}}
   ```
2. Using a `short[][]`, on the `stream` operation just add a `sorted()` operation to be sure to keep the order. It'll iterate over the differents `arguments` and `values` and if there is the corresponding `Pair` in the initial list, it'll set the good index to `1`, if not `0`

   ```
   ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val1"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val2"));
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag1", "val4"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag2", "val2"));       
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag2", "val4"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val2"));
   list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val2"));  list.add(new Pair<>("ag3", "val3"));

   List<String> arguments = list.stream().map(Pair::getKey).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
   List<String> values = list.stream().map(Pair::getValue).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

   short[][] res = new short[arguments.size()][values.size()];      

   for(int ag = 0 ; ag<arguments.size() ; ag++){
       for(int val = 0 ; val<values.size() ; val++){  
           if(list.contains(new Pair<>(arguments.get(ag),values.get(val)))){
               res[ag][val] = 1;
           }else{
               res[ag][val] = 0;        
           }
       }    
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(res)); 
   // [[1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that uses grouping to simulate the pivot table:

```
List<String> rights = inputArray.stream()
        .map(Pair::getRight)
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Pair<String, Map<String, Boolean>>> mapping = inputArray.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getLeft, 
                    Collectors.mapping(Pair::getRight, Collectors.toSet())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            Map<String, Boolean> values = new HashMap<>();

            rights.stream().forEach(v -> {
                values.put(v, entry.getValue().contains(v) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
            });

            return Pair.of(entry.getKey(), values);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And printing that map results in the following:

```
rights.forEach(r -> System.out.print(r + " | "));
System.out.println();
mapping.forEach((key) -> {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(key.getLeft() + " | ");
    rights.forEach(rr -> sb.append((key.getRight().get(rr) ? "      1" : "      0") + "|"));
    System.out.println(sb);
});
```

Result:

```
            value1 | value2| value3| value4| 
argument1 |       1|      1|      0|      1|
argument2 |       0|      1|      0|      1|
argument3 |       1|      1|      1|      0|
```